# C# audio library (with simple effects, echos, reverb...)

Tags: c#, audio, effects, distortion

could you please me advise some simple, free, library for modify input wav file? I found and try to play with irrKlang, but it misses customizing effect (it doesn't have any level of customization. You can just use effect distortion, but you cannot anything to set)

If there was something similar library, that's would be great. Thanks. for any advice.

Answer (score 6):

There are good C# Audio Libraries for Wav like Bass Audio Library or NAudio :
[Bass Audio Library Link](http://www.un4seen.com/)
[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)
Check their website to see if you find whatever you want there.

Comment: I tried Bass Audio but I've failed... And about NAudio, for me seems little complicated. But I'm to give it second chance.